# Adding filter textbox to header of a Listview in Gridview mode

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, datagrid, filter

I watched a demo video of Mole 2010 (a WPF debugger) in which there is a nice datagrid feature where the header contains a filter textbox, so you can type in a string and filter for that column. Here is the video, the feature is demonstrated at 3:00 minutes

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgMg61iM9G8&feature=player_embedded#at=180

I am interested in replicating that feature, but I am not sure how to do it gracefully. My application is a WPF MVVM EF app, it's my first WPF app.

- Is it possible to create a template for the header where I can also add a textbox, and a button with a cross so the contents can be cleared?
- If so, how could I bind the textbox to filter its column?
- Should I be hiding the actual header row and making an artificial one where I add my own header and textbox and button etc. and then bind them to filter clause properties that I add to my CollectionViewSource when a filter string is typed? I hoped to avoid this so I could retain sorting by clicking the header.

I dont really know how to start this. Are there any gurus that could suggest how this could be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how to use a TextBox for filtering the data in a DataGrid. It uses MVVM and the Entity Framework as well.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try that : http://dotnetexplorer.blog.com/2011/04/07/wpf-itemscontrol-generic-staticreal-time-filter-custom-control-presentation/ => it filters any collections and you just have to decalre the control in XAML...